# How to tune a Ruby on Rails application running on Heroku which uses production level Heroku Postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, stress-testing

The Company I work for decided on moving their entire stack to Heroku. The main motivation was it's ease of use: No sysAdmin, no cry. But I still have some questions about it...

I'm making some load and stress tests on both application platform and Postgres service. I'm using `blitz` as an addon of Heroku. I attack on the site with number of users between 1 to 250. There are some very interesting results I got and I need help on evaluating them.

### The Test Stack:

#### Application specifications

It hasn't anything that much special at all.

- Rails 4.0.4
- Unicorn
- `database.yml` set up to connect to Heroku postgres.
- Not using cache.

#### Database

It's a [Standard Tengu](https://addons.heroku.com/marketplace/heroku-postgresql#standard-tengu) (naming conventions of Heroku will kill me one day :) properly connected to the application.

#### Heroku configs

I applied everything on `unicorn.rb` as told in "[Deploying Rails Applications With Unicorn](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn)" article. I have 2 regular web dynos.

```
WEB_CONCURRENCY  : 2
DB_POOL          : 5
```

#### Data

- `episodes` table counts 100.000~
- `episode_urls` table counts 300.000~
- `episode_images` table counts 75.000~

#### Code

`episodes_controller.rb`

```
  def index
    @episodes = Episode.joins(:program).where(programs: {channel_id: 1}).limit(100).includes(:episode_image, :episode_urls)
  end
```

`episodes/index.html.erb`

```
<% @episodes.each do |t| %>
<% if !t.episode_image.blank? %>
<li><%= image_tag(t.episode_image.image(:thumb)) %></li>
<% end %>
<li><%= t.episode_urls.first.mas_path if !t.episode_urls.first.blank?%></li>
<li><%= t.title %></li>
<% end %>
```

### Scenario #1:

```
Web dynos   : 2
Duration    : 30 seconds
Timeout     : 8000 ms
Start users : 10
End users   : 10
```

#### Result:

```
HITS 100.00% (484)
ERRORS 0.00% (0)
TIMEOUTS 0.00% (0)
```

> This rush generated 218 successful hits in 30.00 seconds and we
>   transferred 6.04 MB of data in and out of your app. The average hit
>   rate of 7.27/second translates to about 627,840 hits/day.

### Scenario #2:

```
Web dynos   : 2
Duration    : 30 seconds
Timeout     : 8000 ms
Start users : 20
End users   : 20
```

#### Result:

```
HITS 100.00% (484)
ERRORS 0.00% (0)
TIMEOUTS 0.00% (0)
```

> This rush generated 365 successful hits in 30.00 seconds and we
>   transferred 10.12 MB of data in and out of your app. The average hit
>   rate of 12.17/second translates to about 1,051,200 hits/day. The
>   average response time was 622 ms.

### Scenario #3:

```
Web dynos   : 2
Duration    : 30 seconds
Timeout     : 8000 ms
Start users : 50
End users   : 50
```

#### Result:

```
HITS 100.00% (484)
ERRORS 0.00% (0)
TIMEOUTS 0.00% (0)
```

> This rush generated 371 successful hits in 30.00 seconds and we
>   transferred 10.29 MB of data in and out of your app. The average hit
>   rate of 12.37/second translates to about 1,068,480 hits/day. The
>   average response time was 2,631 ms.

### Scenario #4:

```
Web dynos   : 4
Duration    : 30 seconds
Timeout     : 8000 ms
Start users : 50
End users   : 50
```

#### Result:

```
HITS 100.00% (484)
ERRORS 0.00% (0)
TIMEOUTS 0.00% (0)
```

> This rush generated 484 successful hits in 30.00 seconds and we
>   transferred 13.43 MB of data in and out of your app. The average hit
>   rate of 16.13/second translates to about 1,393,920 hits/day. The
>   average response time was 1,856 ms.

### Scenario #5:

```
Web dynos   : 4
Duration    : 30 seconds
Timeout     : 8000 ms
Start users : 150
End users   : 150
```

#### Result:

```
HITS 71.22% (386)
ERRORS 0.00% (0)
TIMEOUTS 28.78% (156)
```

> This rush generated 386 successful hits in 30.00 seconds and we
>   transferred 10.76 MB of data in and out of your app. The average hit
>   rate of 12.87/second translates to about 1,111,680 hits/day. The
>   average response time was 5,446 ms.

### Scenario #6:

```
Web dynos   : 10
Duration    : 30 seconds
Timeout     : 8000 ms
Start users : 150
End users   : 150
```

#### Result:

```
HITS 73.79% (428)
ERRORS 0.17% (1)
TIMEOUTS 26.03% (151)
```

> This rush generated 428 successful hits in 30.00 seconds and we
>   transferred 11.92 MB of data in and out of your app. The average hit
>   rate of 14.27/second translates to about 1,232,640 hits/day. The
>   average response time was 4,793 ms. You've got bigger problems,
>   though: 26.21% of the users during this rush experienced timeouts or
>   errors!

### General Summary:

- The "Hit Rate" never  goes beyond the number of 15 even though 150 users sends request to the application.
- Increasing number of web dynos does not help handling requests.

## Questions:

1. When I use caching and memcached (Memcachier add-on from Heroku) even 2 web dynos can handle >180 hits per second. I'm just trying to understand what can dynos and the postgres service can do without cache. This way I'm trying to understand how to tune them. How to do it?
2. Standard Tengu is said to have 200 concurrent connections. So why it never reaches that number?
3. If having a prdouction level db and increasing web dynos won't help to scale my app, what's the point to use Heroku?
4. Probably the most important question: What am I doing wrong? :)

Thank you for even reading this crazy question!

Comment: Most of the usual tuning and diagnostic tools for PostgreSQL like `pg_stat_statements`, `pg_stat_plans`, `auto_explain`, `pgbadger`, etc are not available for Heroku. Nor do you have much you can tune on Heroku even if you want to. That said: How do you determine that the DB never reaches 200 connections? Separately, why would you want it to, unless it has 200 CPUs and a vastly parallel I/O subsystem?

Comment: I'm using `SELECT COUNT(*) from pg_stat_activity;` command in sql console so I can see active connections. that's how I determine number of connections. Shouldn't I suppose to have more than 15 connections while there are 150 requests coming to my application?

Comment: No, not necessarily. Unless the database server is *very* big, you're better off with fewer connections that process requests faster. See http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections

Comment: `pg_stat_statements` is available and included by default on 9.2+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I particularly figured out the issue.

Firstly, remember my code in the view:

```
<% @episodes.each do |t| %>
<% if !t.episode_image.blank? %>
<li><%= image_tag(t.episode_image.image(:thumb)) %></li>
<% end %>
<li><%= t.episode_urls.first.mas_path if !t.episode_urls.first.blank?%></li>
<li><%= t.title %></li>
<% end %>
```

Here I'm getting each episodes `episode_image` inside my iteration. Even though I've been using `includes` in my controller, there was a big mistake at my table schema. **I did not have index for `episode_id` in my `episode_images` table!**. This was causing an extremely high query time. I've found it using New Relic's database reports. All other query times were 0.5ms or 2-3ms but `episode.episode_image` was causing almost 6500ms!

I don't know much about the relationship between query time and application execution but as I added index to my `episode_images` table, now I can clearly see the difference. If you have your database schema properly, you'll probably won't face any problem with scaling via Heroku. But any dyno can not help you with a badly designed database.

For people who might run into same problem, I would like to tell you about some of my findings of relationship between Heroku web dynos, Unicorn workers and Postgresql active connections:

Basically, Heroku provides you a dyno which is some kind of a small virtual machine having 1 core and 512MB ram. Inside that little virtual machine, your Unicorn server runs. Unicorn has a master process and worker processes. Each of your Unicorn workers has their own permanent connection to your existing Postgresql server (Don't forget to check out [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn)) It basically means that when you have a Heroku dyno up with 3 Unicorn workers running on it, you have at least 4 active connections. If you have 2 web dynos, you have at least 8 active connections.

Let's say you have a Standard Tengu Postgres with 200 concurrent connections limit. If you have problematic queries with bad db design neither can db nor more dynos can save you without cache... If you have long running queries you have no choice other than caching, I think.

All above is my own findings, if there is anything wrong with them please warn me by your comments.

Comment: Thanks for commenting about your solution.
My first question would have been to compare the performance you see on heroku against local performance, which would have revealed same (relative) performance, and would have highlighted the missing indexes.

eg. Why is the performance on Heroku so much different than my local testing?

Comment: In fact, you'd better post this questions as a "question" and by this way others would access easily to the answers. Once you created them, let me know the link, okay?